# Group by Enum with columns as Date, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm doing an inner join where i select between a date range (say, BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'), and grouping by an enumerated value. is there a way to do this for each month as a column for a range of months? I'm currently doing this by hand for each month.

Example:

```
vehicle_type  | January    | February | March
----------------------------------------------
sedan         |     12     |   10     |  4
coupe         |     5      |   7      |  23
truck         |     0      |   0      |  9
electric      |     22     |   10     |  13
hybrid        |     0      |   12     |  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calendar table...

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
(
  description  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  when_start   DATE,
  when_end     DATE
)
```

then use a pivot query
e.g.

```
SELECT 
    vehicle_type,
    SUM(jan),SUM(feb),
    --add the other months here 
    SUM(nov),SUM(dece) 
FROM 
(
SELECT v.vehicle_type,
CASE WHEN c.description='Jan' THEN
    count(*)
END AS jan,
case when c.description='Feb' THEN
    count(*)
END AS feb,
-- Add the rest of the months here too 
CASE WHEN c.description='Nov' THEN
    COUNT(*)
END AS nov,
CASE WHEN c.description='Dec' THEN
    COUNT(*)
END AS dece
FROM calendar c
INNER JOIN vehicles v ON v.when >= c.when_start AND v.when <= c.when_end  
GROUP BY v.vehicle_type
)
GROUP BY vehicle_type
ORDER BY vehicle_type
```